# Microsoft Face API - faceId value for the same person is different with each API call

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm using the Microsoft Face API to track people in front of a webcam by sending a screenshot from the camera to the API every second or so

If a particular person is in front of the camera for multiple API calls, the API should return the same faceId for that person in each response, but it is returning a new faceId for that person instead. This makes it impossible for me to know whether there is a new person in front of the camera, or a different person

This was not the case a couple of weeks ago, it's just something which has started happening recently

The parameters that I'm sending are...

```
returnFaceId:true,returnFaceLandmarks:false,returnFaceAttributes:age,gender
```

... the gender and age detection are working fine, it's just the faceId that I'm having problems with

Is there a limit to how many faceIds it'll assign per month or something? I can't find any reference to a limit in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

here is Shuolin from Microsoft Cognitive Service Face Team. Referring to Face Detect API is provided (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236), each Detect API call will return a unique FaceId (even same face is used in different call). For your situation, I suggest that you can use Identify API to recognize person (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239).

Comment: While the links might provide the answer. It's best to paste the relevant pieces in the answer in case the links ever die.

Comment: Thanks @shdi . So from what I can understand, the process for getting a unique persistent ID for a face is [like this flowchart](http://imgur.com/a/t1GJL)